# Book recommendations for Second Language Acquisition

Tags: reference-request, second-lang-acquisition

Can anyone please suggest some good books to read on Second Language Acquisition?

Comment: Second language acquisition is not a major area in linguistics. Unfortunately. You might be interested in [Larry Selinker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Selinker)'s _Interlanguage_ theory of second language learning.

Answer (score 2):

See [my Reading List](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/our-reading-list) that covers all of linguistics! I copy pasted just the books on L2 Acquisition.

> ### L2 Acquisition
>
> 1. Kristen Hummel. *Introducing second language acquisition : perspectives and practices*.
> 2. Muriel Saville-Troike. *Introducing second language acquisition*.
> 3. Lourdes Ortega. *Understanding second language acquisition*.
> 4. Jennifer Larson-Hall. *Second language acquisition myths : applying second language research to classroom teaching* (2012).
> 5. Patsy Lightbown. *How Languages are Learned* (2013 4 ed).
> 6. Rosamund Mitchell. *Second language learning theories* (2013).
> 7. David Michael Singleton. *Key topics in second language acquisition* (2014).
> 8. Rod Ellis. *Understanding second language acquisition* (2015 2 ed).
> 9. Vivian Cook. *Second Language Learning and Language Teaching* (2016 5 ed).
> 10. Roumyana Slabakova. *Second language acquisition* (2016)
> 11. Theodore Rogers. *Approaches and Methods in Language Teaching* (Cambridge Language Teaching Library) (2017 3 ed).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good one for understanding linguistics in order to inform teaching methodology:
Linguistics for Language Teachers: Lessons for Classroom Practice
(Sarah J. Shin and Sunny Park-Johnson)

For phonology:
Phonology for Listening: Teaching the Stream of Speech (Richard Cauldwell).